# How to get text of a button on 'ng-click' event in AngularJS component

Tags: angularjs

I have created a component in AngularJS for reusable buttons. I need to pass button text into a function argument via ng-click event of the same button. However, I am unable to get the button text in a function call.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Below is my code.

**Index.html**

```
<div class="object-actions" ng-repeat="val in value">
   <button-control  ng-repeat="v in val" name="{{v}}"></button-control>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular
    .module("buttonCtrl", [])
    .component("buttonControl", {
      template: `<button ng-click="getName('$ctrl.name')">{{$ctrl.name}}</button>`,
      controller: buttonCtrl,
      bindings: {
        name: "@"
      }
    });

  buttonCtrl.$inject = ["$scope"];

  function buttonCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.getName = function(name) {
      alert(name);
    };
  }
})();
```

**Output**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWHQY.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you pass the variable with quotes and it becomes a string.

> ### ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> ng-click="getName('$ctrl.name')"
> ```

However you don't need to pass it into the function in order to print it, and also there is no need to inject `$scope`:

```
function buttonCtrl() {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.getName = function() {
      alert(ctrl.name);
    };
}
```

### BETTER

```
ng-click="$ctrl.getName()"
```